# Как передать результат выполнения одной функции в другую компоненту React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Первая компонента (нужен результат `clicked`):

```
import React from 'react';
import './header.less';

class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.clicked = this.clicked.bind(this);
  }

  state = {
    flag: false
  }

  clicked() {
    const f = this.state.flag;
    if (f) {
      this.setState({ flag: false });
      console.log('false');
    } else {
      this.setState({ flag: true });
      console.log(true);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id='header'>
        <div className='container'>
          <div className='header'>
            <div className='logo col-md-2 col-4'><h1>Sizov</h1></div>
            <div className='authorization col-md-10 col-8'>
              <i className='menu_icon' onClick={this.clicked}><img src='../../assets/header/menu.png' /></i>
              <a>Sing in</a>
              <a>Sing up</a>
              <div className='input_search'>
                <input placeholder='Search' type='text'/>
                <i></i>
              </div>
              <a><img href='#' src='./../../assets/header/shopping-purse-icon.png'/><div className='red_dot'><span>0</span></div></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

Вторая компонента (нужно поместить в `show` результат выполнения `clicked`):

```
import React from 'react';
import './menu.less';

class Menu extends React.Component {
  show() {
    if (this.clicked) {
      return true;
    } return false;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id='menu'>
        <div className='container'>
          <div className='menu'>
            <ul className={`${this.show ? 'red' : 'green'}`}>
              <a href='#'><li>Detective</li></a>
              <a href='#'><li>Humor</li></a>
              <a href='#'><li>Fantasy</li></a>
              <a href='#'><li>Poetry</li></a>
              <a href='#'><li>Love story</li></a>
              <a href='#'><li>Childrens literature</li></a>
              <a href='#'><li>Business</li></a>
              <a href='#'><li>Adventure</li></a>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Menu;
```

Comment: Если компонент `Header` не связан с компонентом `Menu`, то стандартными средствами типа `props` не решить вопрос. Однако, при наличии общего родителя можно хранить этот флаг в родителе и через `props` передавать колбэки на изменение стейта родителя.

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я понял, из кода, эти компоненты имеют одного родителя. Если вкратце Header должен передать свой state родителю, а уже родитель через props в Menu. Если родителя общего нет, то стоит смотреть в строну Redux.